# Scrapy 1.1.0 - no active project

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev

I am newbie in Python, installed Scrapy successfully, using PyDev in eclipse. When I run the programm it is showing like this (Figure illustrates)

[[image: error screenshot]]

I am running this code :

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

What is it? Unable to run program.

Comment: what is the command that you are running?

Comment: can you update your question with that?

Comment: And how are you running the code? Do you just push a button in eclipse?

Comment: Yes just Run button (or F 11)

Comment: Scrapy usually needs a project to run. You can run an individual spider by executing `scrapy runspider <spider_file.py>` from a command line. [Documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#runspider)

Comment: How a whole project can be run in Scrapy?

Comment: You should consider [the tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) for that.

Comment: It is so difficult (going to cmd and then run) Is there any easy way to Scrap the HTTP ?

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way with scrapy.

Comment: Any other framework for HTTP data colllector?

Comment: I think scrapy is the right choice for this. And getting comfortable with the command line will become very rewarding after some time.

Comment: Although i agree with @k-nut about the command line (i don't even use an IDE actually...) for simple project you can consider using urllib and beautfifulsoup. They are simpler librairies and more flexible. But you will have to code more if you want to flexibility !

Answer (score 12):

Your current directory is not a Scrapy project.

A scrapy project has a defined format and files. Have a look at: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

You really should go though the tutorial once.

Basically, a Scrapy project has a directory structure as:

```
tutorial/
    scrapy.cfg            # deploy configuration file

    tutorial/             # project's Python module, you'll import your code from here
        __init__.py

        items.py          # project items file

        pipelines.py      # project pipelines file

        settings.py       # project settings file

        spiders/          # a directory where you'll later put your spiders
            __init__.py
            ...
```

To create a scrapy project go to your project folder and run:

```
scrapy startproject projectname
```

After you have created the project, you can now run scrapy from your project root folder. Make sure you are at the root of the project when you run scrapy.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and the solution turned out to be trivial. 
I was trying to run `scrapy crawl name_of_project` at the Pycharm project directory level, not scrapy project directory level. 
Maybe it will help someone, who like me had the same issue despite the good settings.